# How calculate weekley average for each hour fo the day in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, average, moving-average

I'm here again.

I have 3 months long dataset with hourly data.
I need a weekly average for each hour of the day.
So, not a single average value for the entire week, but a value for each hour of the day for a week.

I haven't tried anything, because I don't how I can start.
What I can do, it's share a subset of my dataset with you.

```
structure(list(Hourtime = structure(c(1527804000, 1527807600.73559, 
1527811201.47119, 1527814802.20678, 1527818402.94238, 1527822003.67797
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), HOF = c(0, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5), H_flux = c(-7.9856017965, -5.9197070475, -8.3727508595, 
-17.317657695, -20.81087357, -7.6067714585), LE_flux = c(-0.0788009009557579, 
-1.90920163435432, 0.251986931688322, -1.25918680530234, 0.497851355551565, 
10.6053213610874), Turbulence = c(0.1061918215, 0.08405, 0.1211055835, 
0.208830021, 0.2305439105, 0.219717154), mz31_flux = c(0.02342, 
-0.008085, 0.01424, 0.02375, -0.01505, 0.03235), mz33_flux = c(0.0361, 
-0.0239, -0.1048, -0.0205, 0.2685, 0.2255), mz39_flux = c(-0.057, 
-0.00199999999999999, 0.2345, 0.3745, 0.029, -0.3645), mz42_flux = c(2e-04, 
0.0119, 0.00655, -0.00495, 0.0064, -0.004), mz45_flux = c(0.06575, 
0.028, -0.05065, 0.1115, 0.0844, 0.08305), mz47_flux = c(-0.046, 
0.00685, 0.02795, 0.06215, -0.01425, -0.0383), mz59_flux = c(0.0474, 
0.03845, -0.03475, -0.00784999999999999, 0.07285, -0.10705), 
    mz61_flux = c(-0.01585, 0.01135, 0.03077, 0.01605, -0.0579, 
    0.01725), mz69_flux = c(0.02105, 0.001225, -0.01625, 0.0074, 
    -0.0062, 0.000949999999999998), mz71_flux = c(0.000545, 0.00335, 
    0.00221, -0.01115, 0.00195, -0.0021), mz75_flux = c(-0.00202500000000001, 
    0.00011, 0.0051385, 0.000277500000000003, -0.0012705, -0.00884999999999998
    ), mz79_flux = c(0.010005, 0.00919, -0.0072, -0.02325, -0.0045, 
    -0.03495), mz85_flux = c(-0.007545, -0.00196, -0.013675, 
    0.0037, 0.010395, -0.02955), mz87_flux = c(0.01014, 0.00746, 
    -0.003515, 0.01265, -0.00256, -0.01645), mz93_flux = c(0.01165, 
    0.031, 0.0224, 0.029325, 0.02195, 0.0736), mz99_flux = c(0.00022, 
    0.000495, -0.003895, -0.00068, 0.008325, 0.009685), mz101_flux = c(0.008145, 
    -0.00175, 0.0108, 0.0148, -0.0132, 0.00495), mz107_flux = c(-0.02735, 
    0.0189, 0.0144, 0.0093, -0.00525, -0.0037), mz111_flux = c(0.002505, 
    0.00135, 0.004185, -0.00274, 0.00484, -0.005175), mz113_flux = c(0.00215, 
    0.0012235, 0.00277, 0.002775, -0.00438, -0.00568), mz135_flux = c(-0.00801, 
    0.004815, 0.014065, -0.002315, 0.00317, -0.0119), mz137_flux = c(0.02895, 
    0.008273, -0.03515, 0.00471, 0.014485, 3.73594), mz149_flux = c(-0.00256, 
    0.0001485, 0.004081, -0.00187, -0.00153, 0.002755), mz155_flux = c(-0.000105, 
    0.0005345, -6.435e-05, 0.000846, 1988.94262555, 0.00012)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You want the average for every flux measurement, correct (e.g., one average for mz71 and another for mz149)? Not *over* all of the flux measurements

Comment: Exactly!
Sorry, I didn't specified this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider calculating week difference between each date and the start (i.e., `min(df$Hourtime)`) and calculating hour with `format()`. Then `aggregate` for averages:

```
df <- within(df, {
  # CALCULATE NUMBER OF WEEKS SINCE START
  week <- as.numeric(floor((Hourtime - min(Hourtime)) / (24*60*60*7)), units="secs")
  # EXTRACT HOUR FROM datetime
  hour <- as.integer(format(Hourtime, "%H"))
})

# AGGREGATE FOR MEAN BY WEEK AND HOUR
agg <- aggregate(. ~ week + hour, df, mean)
```

**Output**

```
agg 
#    week hour   Hourtime HOF     H_flux    LE_flux Turbulence mz31_flux mz33_flux mz39_flux mz42_flux mz45_flux mz47_flux mz59_flux mz61_flux mz69_flux mz71_flux
# 1    0   17 1527804000   0  -7.985602 -0.0788009  0.1061918  0.023420    0.0361   -0.0570   0.00020   0.06575  -0.04600   0.04740  -0.01585  0.021050  0.000545
# 2    0   18 1527807601   1  -5.919707 -1.9092016  0.0840500 -0.008085   -0.0239   -0.0020   0.01190   0.02800   0.00685   0.03845   0.01135  0.001225  0.003350
# 3    0   19 1527811201   2  -8.372751  0.2519869  0.1211056  0.014240   -0.1048    0.2345   0.00655  -0.05065   0.02795  -0.03475   0.03077 -0.016250  0.002210
# 4    0   20 1527814802   3 -17.317658 -1.2591868  0.2088300  0.023750   -0.0205    0.3745  -0.00495   0.11150   0.06215  -0.00785   0.01605  0.007400 -0.011150
# 5    0   21 1527818403   4 -20.810874  0.4978514  0.2305439 -0.015050    0.2685    0.0290   0.00640   0.08440  -0.01425   0.07285  -0.05790 -0.006200  0.001950
# 6    0   22 1527822004   5  -7.606771 10.6053214  0.2197172  0.032350    0.2255   -0.3645  -0.00400   0.08305  -0.03830  -0.10705   0.01725  0.000950 -0.002100
#    mz75_flux mz79_flux mz85_flux mz87_flux mz93_flux mz99_flux mz101_flux mz107_flux mz111_flux mz113_flux mz135_flux mz137_flux mz149_flux    mz155_flux
# 1 -0.0020250  0.010005 -0.007545  0.010140  0.011650  0.000220   0.008145   -0.02735   0.002505  0.0021500  -0.008010   0.028950 -0.0025600   -0.00010500
# 2  0.0001100  0.009190 -0.001960  0.007460  0.031000  0.000495  -0.001750    0.01890   0.001350  0.0012235   0.004815   0.008273  0.0001485    0.00053450
# 3  0.0051385 -0.007200 -0.013675 -0.003515  0.022400 -0.003895   0.010800    0.01440   0.004185  0.0027700   0.014065  -0.035150  0.0040810   -0.00006435
# 4  0.0002775 -0.023250  0.003700  0.012650  0.029325 -0.000680   0.014800    0.00930  -0.002740  0.0027750  -0.002315   0.004710 -0.0018700    0.00084600
# 5 -0.0012705 -0.004500  0.010395 -0.002560  0.021950  0.008325  -0.013200   -0.00525   0.004840 -0.0043800   0.003170   0.014485 -0.0015300 1988.94262555
# 6 -0.0088500 -0.034950 -0.029550 -0.016450  0.073600  0.009685   0.004950   -0.00370  -0.005175 -0.0056800  -0.011900   3.735940  0.0027550    0.00012000
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling that data you provided above `df` and using `dplyr` and the `lubridate` package:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(week = lubridate::week(Hourtime),
         hour = lubridate::hour(Hourtime)) %>%
  group_by(week, hour) %>%
  summarize_all(mean)
```

Comment: Thanks @caldwellst.
It seems to work well enough, but I have two doubts/details that I didn't understand.

1) Why it starts to count te first week the 02/06/2018 if my dataset starts the day before (01/06/2018)?

2) I didn't understand that counting criteria of the 'week' in the first column of the result dataframe: why it start with a week 22?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `data.table` and calling the output you gave above `dat`.

```r
dat = structure(...)

library(data.table)

## Make the dataset non-trivial
to_add = seq(dat$Hourtime[5], by = 'hour', length.out = 24*7*3)
for(i in seq_along(to_add)) {
  h_stamp = to_add[i]
  sub_dat = data.frame(h_stamp, dat[i %% 5 + 1, -1])
  names(sub_dat) = names(dat)
  dat = rbind(dat, sub_dat)
}
dim(dat)
#> [1] 510  29

## Main answer begins here
dt <- data.table(dat)
dt[,c('Week', 'Hour') := .(week(Hourtime), hour(Hourtime))]
means <- dcast(dt, Week + Hour ~ ., value.var = grep('*_flux', names(dt), value = TRUE), fun.aggregate = mean)
means[,.(Week, Hour, H_flux)]
#>     Week Hour     H_flux
#>  1:   22    0 -12.845204
#>  2:   22    1 -19.064266
#>  3:   22    2 -14.398238
#>  4:   22    3  -6.952654
#>  5:   22    4  -7.146229
#>  6:   22    5 -12.845204
#>  7:   22    6 -19.064266
#>  8:   22    7 -14.398238
#>  9:   22    8  -6.952654
#> 10:   22    9  -7.146229
#> 11:   22   10 -12.845204
#> 12:   22   11 -19.064266
#> 13:   22   12 -14.398238
#> 14:   22   13  -6.952654
#> 15:   22   14  -7.146229
#> 16:   22   15 -12.845204
#> 17:   22   16 -19.064266
#> 18:   22   17 -14.398238
#> 19:   22   18  -7.296970
#> 20:   22   19  -6.737388
#> 21:   22   20 -11.354386
#> 22:   22   21 -18.482063
#> 23:   22   22 -13.881764
#> 24:   22   23  -7.471208
#> 25:   23    0 -10.615986
#> 26:   23    1 -10.671293
#> 27:   23    2 -12.299571
#> 28:   23    3 -14.076446
#> 29:   23    4 -12.743295
#> 30:   23    5 -10.615986
#> 31:   23    6 -10.671293
#> 32:   23    7 -12.299571
#> 33:   23    8 -14.076446
#> 34:   23    9 -12.743295
#> 35:   23   10 -10.615986
#> 36:   23   11 -10.671293
#> 37:   23   12 -12.299571
#> 38:   23   13 -14.076446
#> 39:   23   14 -12.743295
#> 40:   23   15 -10.615986
#> 41:   23   16 -10.671293
#> 42:   23   17 -12.299571
#> 43:   23   18 -14.076446
#> 44:   23   19 -12.743295
#> 45:   23   20 -10.615986
#> 46:   23   21 -10.671293
#> 47:   23   22 -12.299571
#> 48:   23   23 -14.076446
#> 49:   24    0 -14.076446
#> 50:   24    1 -12.743295
#> 51:   24    2 -10.615986
#> 52:   24    3 -10.671293
#> 53:   24    4 -12.299571
#> 54:   24    5 -14.076446
#> 55:   24    6 -12.743295
#> 56:   24    7 -10.615986
#> 57:   24    8 -10.671293
#> 58:   24    9 -12.299571
#> 59:   24   10 -14.076446
#> 60:   24   11 -12.743295
#> 61:   24   12 -10.615986
#> 62:   24   13 -10.671293
#> 63:   24   14 -12.299571
#> 64:   24   15 -14.076446
#> 65:   24   16 -12.743295
#> 66:   24   17 -10.615986
#> 67:   24   18 -10.671293
#> 68:   24   19 -12.299571
#> 69:   24   20 -14.076446
#> 70:   24   21 -12.743295
#> 71:   24   22 -10.615986
#> 72:   24   23 -10.671293
#> 73:   25    0 -12.081318
#> 74:   25    1 -12.081318
#> 75:   25    2 -12.081318
#> 76:   25    3 -12.081318
#> 77:   25    4 -12.081318
#> 78:   25    5 -12.081318
#> 79:   25    6 -12.081318
#> 80:   25    7 -12.081318
#> 81:   25    8 -12.081318
#> 82:   25    9 -12.081318
#> 83:   25   10 -12.081318
#> 84:   25   11 -12.081318
#> 85:   25   12 -12.081318
#> 86:   25   13 -12.081318
#> 87:   25   14 -12.081318
#> 88:   25   15 -12.081318
#> 89:   25   16 -12.081318
#> 90:   25   17 -12.081318
#> 91:   25   18 -12.081318
#> 92:   25   19 -12.081318
#> 93:   25   20 -12.081318
#> 94:   25   21 -12.081318
#> 95:   25   22 -13.105247
#> 96:   25   23 -13.621721
#>     Week Hour     H_flux
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Reconsider using `rbind` inside a loop which leads to excessive copying in memory.

Comment: Absolutely. That was simply the easiest way for me to extend this dataset so that the result wasn't trivial. `rbind` inside a for loop is generally a bad idea.